# creating vectors for individually parsed sentences c++

Tags: c++, parsing, vector

```
class Read
{
public:
    Read(const char* filename)
    :mFile(filename)
    {

    }
    void setString()
    {
        while(getline(mFile, str, '.'))
        {
            getline(mFile, str, '.');
            str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());
        }

    }
private:
    ifstream mFile;
    string str;
};


int main()
{
    Read r("sample.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

My ultimate goal is to parse through each sentence in the file so I used getline setting the delimiter to '.' to get each individual sentence. I want to create a sentence vector but am not really sure how to do so.

The file is pretty big so it will have a lot of sentences. How do I create a vector for each sentence?

Will it simply be vector < string > str? How will it know the size?

EDIT: I added a line of code to remove the '\n'
EDIT: Got rid of !eof

Comment: it won't know the size, when you `push_back` a string if it's size was not enough vector will allocate more memory for new strings.

Comment: So, is that all you wanted to do?  Clearly, you have a single `vector` containing all the sentences, rather than "a `vector` for each sentence", but if you really do want the latter you'd need to specify rules for splitting sentences.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(!myFile.eof())
        getline(mFile, str, '.');
```

Where did you find that?  Please put it back.  Try:

```
std::vector<std::string> sentences;

while(std::getline(mFile, str, '.'))
    sentences.push_back(str);
```

The `vector` container has a `.size()` function to return the number of populated elements.  You should google "std::vector" and read through the functions in the API.

Comment: I got it from my textbook. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @user3239138: yikes - that's honestly *terrible*.  The `eof()` status is only set on a stream after attempting some input and encountering the end of file... say you file contains "abc\n", then the first `getline` call will read "abc" but `eof` will not be set, then the second `getline()` will fail with `eof()` set.  If you test `eof` before and independently of calling `getline`, and do not test for success of `getline` itself, you'll get the false impression that the second `getline` call found a second line in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors are dynamica arrays. You need not to worry about the size of the vector. You can use `push_back()` function to add element in the vector. I have made some changes in your code. Please check if this work for you..

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Read
{
public:
    Read(const char* filename)
    :mFile(filename)
    {

    }
    void setString()
    {
        while(getline(mFile, str, '.'))
        {
            vec.push_back(str);
        }
    }
private:
    ifstream mFile;
    string str;
    vector<string> vec;
};
int main()
{
    Read r("sample.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(!myFile.eof())` is broken... `eof()` won't be set until after input is attempted (here, `getline`) and eof is encountered.  For a text file, that means it's only set when trying to read the last line in the file that doesn't have a newline delimiter (and that may be otherwise empty too).

Comment: I have added another line of code to get rid of the newline delimiter. That should be ok right?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

...

vector<string> sentences;
sentences.push_back(line);
```

The vector is a dynamic array and it will resize itself as you keep adding sentences. If you know the number of sentences, you can increase the performance by calling:

```
sentences.resize(number of sentences here)
```